# BizTalk integration into Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, windows-server-2012, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to integrate the BizTalk 2013 R2 templates into Visual Studio 2012 for a work project.

I tried to repair the BizTalk installation, but I still cannot find the BizTalk templates in Visual Studio.

I am using the two programs on a Windows Server 2012 workstation.

Can anyone help me understand what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those interested in an answer, BizTalk 2013 R2 only works with the 2013 edition of Visual Studio. Therfore you will need to install this edition for it to be integrated.

Comment: Better mark this as the answer then ;-)  And yes, each version of BizTalk only work with one particular version of Visual Studio. BizTalk 2013 is Visual Studio 2012.  BizTalk 2013 R2 as noted is Visual Studio 2013.